# Buttons with very similar code aren't both working. Why?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I am writing a very basic code to make a dot move around on a screen.  My goal is to eventualy have an adventure game.  It is mostly GUI, but I am having some problems with my buttons.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class gui {
    int x = 240;
    int y = 240;
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    MyDrawPanel drawpanel = new MyDrawPanel();
    public void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DotMover");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawpanel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel1);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        drawpanel.repaint();

        JButton leftbutton = new JButton("<----");
        leftbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                x = x - 1;
                drawpanel.repaint();
            }
        });
        panel1.add(leftbutton);

        JButton rightbutton = new JButton("---->");
        rightbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                x++;
                drawpanel.repaint();
            }
        });
        panel1.add(rightbutton);

        JButton upbutton = new JButton("Up");
        upbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                y++;
                drawpanel.repaint();
            }
        });
        panel1.add(upbutton);

        JButton downbutton = new JButton("Down");
        upbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                y = y - 1;
                drawpanel.repaint();
            }
        });
        panel1.add(downbutton);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 20, 20);
        }
    }
}

public class dotmoveriii {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        gui a = new gui();
        a.go();
    }
}
```

When I run it on my computer, the left and right buttons work but the up and down buttons don't.  What's up whith that?

Comment: please indent your code so it is readable

Comment: the action listener is not set on the downlistener

Comment: if you use `x++`, why you're not using `x--` (instead of `x = x - 1`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You added two action listeners that undo each others effects to the up button, and no action listeners on the down button. That's why neither button produces any visible effect.

One button can have multiple action listeners. In effect, your up button moves the oval up, and then immediately down. The overall effect is that the oval stays in place.

Obviously, all you need to do is fixing your copy-paste error:

```
downbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        y++; // The "up" button should be y--, because the y axis points down
        drawpanel.repaint();
    }
});
```

(note the use of `y--` instead of `y = y - 1`. Since you are already have a `++`, there is no reason not to have a `--`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here :

```
JButton upbutton = new JButton("Up");
upbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {                
        y++;
        drawpanel.repaint();
    }
});
panel1.add(upbutton);

JButton downbutton = new JButton("Down");
upbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        y = y - 1;
        drawpanel.repaint();
    }
});
panel1.add(downbutton);
```

After creating the `downbutton`, you are adding the listener once again to the `upbutton` instead of the `downbutton`.

Therefore, each time the `upbutton` is clicked, 1 will be added then removed after the second listener. And when pressing the `downbutton`, nothing will be done, this is why the circle was never moving.

**Also**, your logic is incorrect. To go down you need to add +1 instead of removing one, else the behaviour will be reversed.

**Also**, I've notice that you used `y = -1` and `y++`. Note that you can also do `y--`